# MVC CSV Import and calculate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a MVC application in which I can import a .csv file with a particular structure. The view renders the data as expected. I now need to calculate goal difference and also identify the team with the lowest goal difference.

I have done the goal difference calculation in the model and it works, this is probably not the best place to do it so any advice there would be welcomed. What I really need help with is identifying the team with the lowest int in goal difference and then displaying that team name in the view.

Controller

```
using CSVImport.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;

namespace CSVImport.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new List<Team>());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
        {
            try
            {

                List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();
                string filePath = string.Empty;
                if (postedFile != null)
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    }

                    filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                            
                    //Loop through rows skip the header row
                    foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\r', '\n').Skip(1))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                        {
                            teams.Add(new Team
                            {
                                TeamName = row.Split(',')[0],
                                Played = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[1]),
                                Won = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[2]),
                                Loss = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[3]),
                                Draw = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[4]),
                                GoalsFor = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[5]),
                                GoalsAgainst = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[6]),
                                Points = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[7])                                
                            });    
                        }
                    }
                }
                return View(teams);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CSVImport.Models
{
    public class Team
    {
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public int Played { get; set; }
        public int Won { get; set; }
        public int Loss { get; set; }
        public int Draw { get; set; }
        public int GoalsFor { get; set; }
        public int GoalsAgainst { get; set; }

        //Calculates Goal Difference, should probably be done in HomeController but need to figure out how...
        public int Difference //{ get; set; }
        {
            get
            {
                var d = GoalsFor - GoalsAgainst;
                return d;
            }
        }
        public int Points { get; set; }

        //Find lowest goal difference should also probably be done in controller
        public string Lowest
        {
            get
            {
                var low = Team.TeamName.Min(a => a.Difference);
                return low;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think that `GoalsFor` and `GoalsAgainst are properties of a` Team`, why wouldn't` GoalDifference` be a property? The only thing that I would do is simplify the property:

```
public int Difference => this.GoalsFor - this.GoalsAgainst;
```

or if you are using an older version of C#

```
public int Difference { get {return this.GoalsFor - this.GoalsAgainst;} }
```

> What I really need help with is identifying the team with the lowest int in goal difference and then displaying that team name in the view.

To find the team with the lowest value for GoalDifference, you need to have a collection of Teams. This will probably be a `List<Team>`, or `Team[]`, but in fact any enumerable sequence of Teams will do.

Class Team is not the proper place to do this. This class does not represent a sequence of Teams.

If you have a sequence of Teams, then finding the team with the lowest Difference is easy:

```
IEnumerable<Team> teams = ...
Team teamWithLowestDifference = teams.OrderBy(team => team.Difference)
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: order the sequence of teams by ascending value of Team.Difference. From the result take the first one, or null if there are no teams at all.

```
Team  Difference
  A      4
  B      5
  C      2      <== lowest Difference
  D      3
```

After OrderBy: C, D, A, B
Take the first: C

Although this will work, it is not very efficient. If you found the element that should be first in your ordered sequence, why order the rest of your sequence if you won't use the result anyway?

An easy to understand method, would be an extension method for `IEnumerable<Team>`.
See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx).
This way you can use it as if it was a LINQ method.

```
public static class TeamExtensions
{
    public Team LowestDifferenceOrDefault(this IEnumerable<Team> teams)
    {
        int lowestDifference = int.MaxValue;
        Team teamWithLowestDifference = null;

        foreach (var team in teams)
        {
            if (team.Difference < lowestDifference)
            {
                 teamWithLowestDifference = team;
                 lowestDifference = team.Difference;
            }
        }
        return teamWithLowestDifference;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Team> myTeams = ...
Team teamWithLowestDifference = myTeams.LowestDifferenceOrDefault();
```

This works even within a LINQ sequence:

```
Team newYorkTeamWithLowestDifference = myTeams
    .Where(team => team.Location == "New York")
    .LowestDifferenceOrDefault();
```

Be aware: if there are two teams with equal lowest difference, it is not guaranteed which team you get. I expect this is not a problem, because you were talking about "the" team with the lowest Difference.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am sitting here, bored during isolation and trying to sharpen my skills. As for the first part of your answer, I simply was not sure if the calculation portion should be done within the controller instead of the model. Your one line is certainly much cleaner. When using the extension, is this something I would add into the controller or should I use a separate model to get this? Also, how would I go about calling this in the view? I have tried using @Team.LowestDifferenceOrDefault but it is giving me an object reference error.

Comment: So I have changed the call in the view to ```@{CSVImport.Controllers.TeamExtensions.LowestDifferenceOrDefault(this.Model);}``` This gets rid of the error. On the other hand, the extension method returns the first team it comes across which is not the team with the lowest difference. In fact it does not iterate through the ```foreach``` block. Also the team name is not returned to the view. Any help with that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I told you before: Team is not a sequence. You can only ask for the team with the lowest difference if you have a sequence of teams, like a List or an array. If you only have one Team, then this team is the one with the lowest difference. I think that is not your problem: somewhere you have a collection of Teams. About the location: as this is an extension of your collection of teams, put it where you've got your team collection, or if you don't have a collection class, put it near Team. After all, isn't that where people search for it?